# Term for wordplay using adjacent repetition of homophones

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for the kind of wordplay in which homophones are repeated adjacently with different meaning? For example,

> The **rose rose** up.
>
> **Rose rows** in church.

Comment: By repeating a word, do you mean that the words are [homophones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone)? These sound the same, have different meanings, and can be spelled the same but don't have to be: the beautiful *rose rose* up, *rows rose* in church.

Comment: Wow your example is much better than mine. May I use it in my original post?

Comment: Please feel free to use my examples if they help you clarify your question, @Shawn!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jim Wegryn calls it a [dittogram](https://www.lingerandlook.com/Words/Homophones.htm).

Comment: +1 Your link has a lot of very good examples! I also remember the famous Buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo Buffalo Buffalo. I can't find any dictionary saying that the word dittogram is really what Jim Wegryn says though.. All I can find is "mistaken repetition of a letter, word, or phrase by a copyist" (dittography)

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo' ?

Answer (score 3):

This [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-twister) refers to them as "alliterations".

It uses one of my favorite limeriks as an example (note that 4:04 is spoken as 'four-four'):

```
There's a train at 4:04 said Miss Jenny. 
Four tickets I'll take. Have you any? 
Said the man at the door. "Not four for 4:04, 
For four for 4:04 is too many."
```

However, "alliteration" is a broader term which can apply to repeated syllables and sounds, and not just complete words.

Maybe there isn't a specific word for what you're describing, but you can hone it down to a phrase: ***"homophones used for alliteration"***.

Comment: That's a nice one. I used to like the German "wenn Fliegen hinter Fliegen fliegen, fliegen Fliegen Fliegen hinterher" but it's only 5 flies, opposed to 9 fours.

Comment: I remember from when I was learning German decades ago: "Die Männer, die vorm Schokoladen Laden Ladenläden laden, laden Ladenmädchen gern zum Tanze ein." (Apologies if I got it wrong; I'm doing this from memory since I've forgotten most of my German).

Answer (score 2):

There is no special term.  *Alliteration* focuses on initial sounds (the graveyard 'Peace, perfect peace') while *rhyme* is about endings (stressed syllable onward e.g. Nash's  'rhinocerous - prepocerous'). *Consonance* is about consonants (the c-v-c syllables 'live, love') and *assonance* about nearby vowel sounds ('high rise').
A published example of mine achieves 11 homophone repetitions, and is entirely plausible teaching (especially for philosophy students, poor things).

> We are here, but for others distant we are 'over there', so our 'here' is their 'there'.
>   Please don't cry.  We are here, but I see you writhe ere 'their there'.  There, there — they're there! Their 'there' they're therefore seeing as over here.
>     That's it really.  Let's celebrate, cohere.  Hear here 'Hear, hear!' Here, heroes all, ends the lesson, succinctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the word homophone

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone

Comment: No, I am looking for the term describing the usage of homophones (or even better, homonyms) in a sentence as a play on words...