# What is it called when your first and last name begin with the same sound/letter?

Tags: single-word-requests

I believe there is a term for your first and last name beginning with the same sound/letter, but I don't know what it is.
Example:
Bobby Brown;
Cindy Cinnamon;
Graham Gusto.

Comment: **Alliteration**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Term for wordplay using adjacent repetition of homophones](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38930/term-for-wordplay-using-adjacent-repetition-of-homophones) Also [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5621/repeating-the-consonant-in-many-words-in-a-sentence-or-phrase/5622#5622)

Comment: Child abuse, no? I presume Cindy dances and Graham bakes.